# Fetching value via promise Angular in custom service

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, angular2-services

I have this code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { AppSettings } from './shared';

@Injectable()
export class HttpClient {

    constructor(private http: Http, private storage: Storage) { }

    createAuthorizationHeader(headers: Headers) {
        var token: string = '';
        this.storage.get(AppSettings.StorageKeys.Token).then(value => {
            token = value;
        });
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
    }

    get(url) {
        let headers = new Headers();
        this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);
        return this.http.get(url, {
            headers: headers
        });
    }

    post(url, data) {
        let headers = new Headers();
        this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);
        return this.http.post(url, data, {
            headers: headers
        });
    }
}
```

The problem here is:

```
this.storage.get(AppSettings.StorageKeys.Token).then(value => {
            token = value;
        });
```

This is promise. So how do I change the `createAuthorizationHeader` function such the headers are appended properly?

This is Ionic2 code but mostly the issue is related to working of promises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`createAuthorizationHeader` isn't returning a promise, and you should create `Authorization` token from promise function success. Also `get` of your service should return promise, for the same you could use `.toPromise()` to return `promise` inspite of Observable. But as you don't won't to loose observable sauce, you should consider converting `createAuthorizationHeader` method to return `Observable`. `Observable.fromPromise` will rescue us in this situation to convert `Promise` to `Observable`.

**Code**

```
createAuthorizationHeader(headers: Headers) {
    var token: string = '';
    let headers = new Headers();
    return Observable.fromPromise(this.storage.get(AppSettings.StorageKeys.Token)
      .then(value => {
        token = value;
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
        return headers;
      }
    );
}

get(url) {
    return this.createAuthorizationHeader()
     .switchMap((headers)=> this.http.get(url, {
        headers: headers
      });
    })
}
```

Comment: @TimLiberty switchMap will switch control over other Observable, in current case it switched to `http.get` method and returned that Observable.. :p Your welcome bhai :) Feel free to ask if you need anything else in answer

Comment: @TimLiberty does it helped??

Comment: superb! Thanks for clearing the confusion. Marked as answer.

Answer (score 2):

Return a header promise and then chain the http call from that promise. Also `get` method should return promise inspite of `Observable`, for the same you could use `.toPromise()` over `http.get` method.

```
createAuthorizationHeader() {
    return this.storage.get(AppSettings.StorageKeys.Token).then(value => {
        let headers = new Headers();
        var token: string = '';
        token = value;
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
        return headers;
    });
}

get(url) {
    //let headers = new Headers();
    return this.createAuthorizationHeader().then(headers => {
        return this.http.get(url, { headers: headers }).toPromise();
    });
}
```

Do the same with the `post` function.

---

> I would lose the Observable and have to work with promises.

If you wish to work with observables, convert the promise after chaining the two promises:

```
get(url) {
    //let headers = new Headers();
    var promise = this.createAuthorizationHeader().then(headers => {
        return this.http.get(url, { headers: headers }).toPromise();
    });
    return Observable.fromPromise(promise);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So effectively I would lose the Observable and have to work with promises. Isn't it?

Comment: @TimLiberty you could easily being stay with observable by converting `createAuthorizationHeader ` to return Observable.

Comment: @PankajParkar: Could you post as an answer?

Comment: @TimLiberty can you add `this.storage.get` method code please?? or is it some plugin/built in thing?

Comment: this.storage.get returns a promise. It is a built thing in Ionic 2.

Comment: The promise can be converted to an Observable. See update to the answer.